# Read from file descriptor and write to stdout

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, file-descriptors, exec

I want to prepend something to each line of output in a script, for every command.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
rm foo
mkfifo foo

exec 3<>foo

cat <&3 | while read line; do
   if [[ -n "$line" ]]; then
    echo " [prepend] $line";
   fi
done &

echo "foo" >&3
echo "bar" >&3
echo "baz" >&3
```

basically for all commands I want to prepend something to each line of the output. My code above is fairly bogus, but I don't quite know how to do it, it's something like the above but not quite.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming script produces:

```
L1
L2

L4
L5
```

then the following command

```
script | sed 's/^\(.\+\)/ \[prepend\] \1/'
```

prepends " [prepend] " to each non-empty line:

```
 [prepend] L1
 [prepend] L2

 [prepend] L4
 [prepend] L5
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the `DEBUG` trap in bash.  From `man builtins`:

```
If a sigspec is DEBUG, the command arg is executed before every simple command,
for command, case command, select command, every arithmetic  for  command,  and
before  the  first  command  executes  in  a  shell function (see SHELL GRAMMAR
above).  Refer to the description of the extdebug option to the  shopt  builtin
for  details of its effect on the DEBUG trap.  If a sigspec is RETURN, the com‐
mand arg is executed each time a shell function or a script executed with the .
or source builtins finishes executing.
```

So, you could set up a debug function like this.  Since it runs before commands you could use it to prepend to your output.

```
#!/bin/bash

debug() {
   : # echo or other commands here
}

trap debug DEBUG

# Commands here
```

Answer (score 0):

This exact code seems to do what I want, but not sure how safe it is:

```
rm foo
mkfifo foo

exec 3<>foo

(
    cat <&3 | while read line; do
       if [[ -n "$line" ]]; then
        echo " [prepend] $line";
       fi
    done &
 )

echo ""  >&3;
echo ""  >&3;
echo "foo" >&3
echo "bar" >&3
echo "baz" >&3


pkill -P $$
```